# Best way for debugging docker build error

Tags: debugging, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build docker image from the dockerfile and currently let's say I have 20-30 commands. And if my build fail in error in 25th command I again have to run the whole build process from the start.

Is there any right solution for building docker containers?

Comment: Containers are not built  from images. Maybe you mean you're trying to build an image from a Dockerfile?

Comment: exactly everytime anything goes wrong i have to re run the docker build

Comment: @ujwaldhakal Why dont you make an image with the first 24 commands, and then create another one from the first? After you are done you can merge the two dockerfiles in one

Comment: Thats something good idea but making image with 24 commands also same na if failed at one point the whole image needs to rebuild